# Updating position of JSlider Swing

Tags: java, swing, jslider

My apologies for posting tons of questions as of late.

I'm trying to get a JSlider to update its position based on a constantly updating variable.

The setValue(n) method doesn't seem to work. Is there any alternative? We're using this as a time marker for a music player.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you've correctly configured a minimum and maximum value, `setValue()` will work. The `JSlider` does need an opportunity to redraw, so make sure you're not tying up the [event dispatch thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread). If your code is responding to any UI event, you're on the dispatch thread and should return as soon as possible.

Perform any expensive calculations on a background thread. There are a plethora of [excellent tutorials](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for this on the web.

Answer (score 0):

The `setValue` method definitely does work, so I would check that the value that you're passing in to `setValue` is indeed within the minimum and maximum value that you've configured the slider with (ie check that you're not passing a percentage value in instead of an integer).

A second thing to watch out for: you should only be calling `setValue` on the event dispatching thread. Of course you can calculate the value that is going to be passed to `setValue` outside of the even dispatching thread, but any update to a value in a Swing component should be done in the even dispatching thread (ie using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`)